# Getting max and min values in rolling manner i.e. for every 3,5,7,10 days max value and min value using groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

DataFrame is as follows

```
BCode   Group   Type    Open    High    Low Close   Last    PClose  TradesB TTQB    TTVB    ISIN    Date    AvgPr
0   500002  A   Q   2810.00 2858.35 2809.85 2843.30 2843.55 2806.20 2454    77454   219527943.00    INE117A01022    06-Jan-23   2834.30
1   500003  A   Q   347.90  347.90  337.25  341.50  342.00  342.20  1177    21940   7462278.00  INE208C01025    06-Jan-23   340.12
2   500008  A   Q   575.15  588.95  575.15  585.80  582.70  574.85  1297    33943   19871165.00 INE885A01032    06-Jan-23   585.43
3   500009  X   Q   27.05   27.35   26.70   27.00   27.00   27.05   249 66931   1798686.00  INE432A01017    06-Jan-23   26.87
4   500010  A   Q   2622.65 2635.15 2590.00 2594.85 2594.85 2622.60 3134    18006   46983906.00 INE001A01036    06-Jan-23   2609.35
```

I want max of High for every 3,5,7,10 days for every unique ISIN.

cumsum does not work as it gives max of entire column.

I tried using cumsum it gives max of groupby('ISIN').

I am expectng following:

I want max of High for every 3,5,7,10 days for every unique ISIN.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can get max `"High"` values for each ISIN for example like this:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# 3D means 3 days
x = df.groupby('ISIN').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Date').rolling('3D', min_periods=1)['High'].max())
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
ISIN          Date      
INE001A01036  2023-01-06    2635.15
INE117A01022  2023-01-06    2858.35
              2023-01-07    2859.35
              2023-01-08    2859.35
              2023-01-09    2859.35
              2023-01-10    2848.35
INE208C01025  2023-01-06     347.90
INE432A01017  2023-01-06      27.35
INE885A01032  2023-01-06     588.95
Name: High, dtype: float64
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
    BCode Group Type     Open     High      Low    Close     Last   PClose  TradesB   TTQB         TTVB          ISIN       Date    AvgPr
0  500002     A    Q  2810.00  2858.35  2809.85  2843.30  2843.55  2806.20     2454  77454  219527943.0  INE117A01022 2023-01-06  2834.30
0  500002     A    Q  2810.00  2859.35  2809.85  2843.30  2843.55  2806.20     2454  77454  219527943.0  INE117A01022 2023-01-07  2834.30
0  500002     A    Q  2810.00  2848.35  2809.85  2843.30  2843.55  2806.20     2454  77454  219527943.0  INE117A01022 2023-01-08  2834.30
0  500002     A    Q  2810.00  2838.35  2809.85  2843.30  2843.55  2806.20     2454  77454  219527943.0  INE117A01022 2023-01-09  2834.30
0  500002     A    Q  2810.00  2828.35  2809.85  2843.30  2843.55  2806.20     2454  77454  219527943.0  INE117A01022 2023-01-10  2834.30
1  500003     A    Q   347.90   347.90   337.25   341.50   342.00   342.20     1177  21940    7462278.0  INE208C01025 2023-01-06   340.12
2  500008     A    Q   575.15   588.95   575.15   585.80   582.70   574.85     1297  33943   19871165.0  INE885A01032 2023-01-06   585.43
3  500009     X    Q    27.05    27.35    26.70    27.00    27.00    27.05      249  66931    1798686.0  INE432A01017 2023-01-06    26.87
4  500010     A    Q  2622.65  2635.15  2590.00  2594.85  2594.85  2622.60     3134  18006   46983906.0  INE001A01036 2023-01-06  2609.35
```